# Proving a set has measure zero

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f\colon (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. Suppose there exists a $C>0$ such that for all $0<a<b<1$, we have $\int_a^b f \geq C(b-a)$. I want to show that $f \neq 0$ almost everywhere on $(0,1).$

I think I have a proof of this, but it's rather long and complicated. I'm hoping there is a much simpler proof. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you mean $$ \begin{align} & \text{For all } 0<a<b<1,\, \left( \int_a^b f \ge C(b-a) \text{ for some } C \right) \\ \text{or} \\ & \left( \text{For all } 0<a<b<1,\, \int_a^b f \ge C(b-a) \right) \text{ for some } C \text{ ?} \end{align}$$ I suppose only the second one makes sense, but even so I'd rather see it made explicit, e.g. by putting "for some $C$" before "for all $0<a<b<1$".

Comment: Yeah you're right. I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be trivial if $f$ was assumed to be continuous but without continuity the best way to prove this is to use Lebesgue's Theorem. This theorem says $\frac 1 {b-a} \int_a^{b} f(x)\,dx \to f(a)$ as $b \to a$ almost everywhere so we get $f \geq C$ almost everywhere.

I have assumed integrability of $f$ but I will let you explain why there is no loss of generality in assuming this.

Comment: By "almost everywhere" do you mean "for almost all values of $a$?"

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, that is what 'almost everywhere' means.

Comment: "Almost everywhere" means for almost all values of some particular variable. Sometimes it's nice to see the variable identified explicitly.

Comment: Yeah this helps. Thanks!